# Need more details on Enumerable.Aggregate function

Tags: c#, aggregate-functions

Can you help me to understand,

```
       words.Aggregate((workingSentence, next) => + next + " " + workingSentence);
```

from below code snippet? and it would be great if someone explain me to achive this in C# 1.1.

(Snippet From [MS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548651.aspx))-

```
        string sentence = "the quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog";
        // Split the string into individual words.
        string[] words = sentence.Split(' ');
        // Prepend each word to the beginning of the 
        // new sentence to reverse the word order.
        string reversed = words.Aggregate((workingSentence, next) =>
                                              next + " " + workingSentence);
        Console.WriteLine(reversed);
        // This code produces the following output:
        //
        // dog lazy the over jumps fox brown quick the
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `Aggregate` part of your example translates to something roughly like this:

```
string workingSentence = null;
bool firstElement = true;
foreach (string next in words)
{
    if (firstElement)
    {
        workingSentence = next;
        firstElement = false;
    }
    else
    {
        workingSentence = next + " " + workingSentence;
    }
}
string reversed = workingSentence;
```

The `workingSentence` variable is an *accumulator* that is updated on each iteration of the loop by applying a function to the existing accumulator value and the current element of the sequence; this is performed by the lambda in your example and by the body of the `foreach` loop in my example.

Comment: Thanks and Clear to me, I will try few more example based on this. Also thanks to Gabe and Will.

Answer (score 2):

Although [LukeH's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4184682/need-more-details-on-enumerable-aggregate-function/4184710#4184710) is easier to understand, I think this is a closer approximation of the C# 1.0 translation of the `Aggregate` function call.

`(workingSentence, next) => + next + " " + workingSentence` is a lambda, which means unnamed delegate. In order to translate it we have to create a delegate type that describes it (I call it `StringAggregateDelegate`) and then make the function itself (I call it `AggregateDelegate`). The `Aggregate` function itself gets the first element of its source, then loops over the remaining elements and calls the delegate with the accumulated result and the next element.

```
delegate string StringAggregateDelegate(string, string);

static string AggregateDelegate(string workingSentence, string next)
{
    return next + " " + workingSentence;
}

static string Aggregate(IEnumerable source,
                        StringAggregateDeletate AggregateDelegate)
{
    // start enumerating the source;
    IEnumerator e = source.GetEnumerator();
    // return empty string if the source is empty
    if (!e.MoveNext())
        return "";
    // get first element as our base case
    string workingSentence = (string)e.Current;
    // call delegate on each item after the first one
    while (e.MoveNext())
        workingSentence = AggregateDelegate(workingSentence, (string)e.Current);
    // return the result
    return workingSentence;
}

// now use the Aggregate function:
    string[] words = sentence.Split(' ');
    // Prepend each word to the beginning of the
    // new sentence to reverse the word order.
    string reversed = Aggregate(words,
                                new StringAggregateDelegate(AggregateDelegate));
```

Answer (score 0):

Its pretty simple.

```
string accumulatedText = string.Empty;
foreach(string part in sentence.Split(' '))
  accumulatedText = part + " " + accumulatedText;
```

The linq extension method is roughly equivalent to this:

```
// this method is the lambda 
// (workingSentence, next) => next + " " + workingSentence)
public string Accumulate(string part, string previousResult)
{  
    return part + " " + previousResult;
}

public void Reverse(string original)
{
  string retval = string.Empty;
  foreach(var part in original.Split(' '))
    retval = Accumulate(part, retval);
  return retval;
}
```